# hide address bar android galaxy s3 options

Tags: javascript, android

I have been reading about the Chrome (android) update that auto scrolls the address bar to hide when the user scrolls past the fold.  I want to hide the address bar altogether.  How can I do this.  I have tried every option I could find and still no luck.

I am currently using html code to create a demo that will be presented on the Galaxy S3.  If I could just remove the addressbar, it would help the demo look like an actual app.  Making the demo more realistic.

Any information is considered a great help.

Comment: You can't change the default behaviour of the browser in this way. However I read something recently that a beta version of chrome allows you to make your web page a full screen app. Or at least make it look like it is...Ref link: http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/10/03/google-chrome-beta-31-brings-install-to-homescreen-for-web-apps-with-support-for-full-screen-mode-and-task-switcher-integration/

Comment: @Novocaine88 thanks, is there a way I can at least have the screen start like 50px lower which might hide the address bar as an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I have achieved it:

```
            html{
                background-color: red;
                overflow: hidden;
                /* prevent overscroll bounce iOS & Android */
                position: fixed;
                height: 100%;
                width:100%;
            }
            body{
                background-color: lightgreen;
                overflow-y:scroll;
                -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* iOS velocity scrolling */
                /* prevent overscroll bounce iOS & Android */
                position:fixed;   
                height:100%;
                width:100%;                 
            }
```